# For each minute add row between ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, date-range

I have table with date ranges

[image]

and i need to add rows between this ranges. I must granulate this table to minutes. How can i add this extra rows

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Can you show a sample of what you want for results?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (And remember that most people here want formatted text, not images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: So far I have tried to find a solution in sql because otherwise it's just a script

Comment: and i add tag ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the following:

```
WITH    cte
      AS (SELECT    CAST('2017-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS startTime
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, startTime)
          FROM      cte
          WHERE     startTime < '2017-01-02 00:00:00'
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
```

OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)

It will give you a minute by minute result.  Substitute in the range you want. You can then use that as a basis to write an insert. Iterative CTE's aren't the most efficient, but probably the easiest

Comment: While his levels of recursion cover ranges such as the example, I'm sure this will be fine.  Although, for the OP to make use of this I suspect you may need to review your answer to his specific case *(I doubt the OP will already know how to amend the CTE to start with the rows he has and stop at appropriate points.)*

Comment: @MatBailie you're probably right.  What I've posted here is more a stepping stone to get to the answer, rather than a complete solution. Your solution is a far fuller answer and gets a +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive CTE option from @MatthewBaker would only need minor changes to meet your needs.

```
WITH
   by_minute
AS
(
    SELECT *, datetime_from, minute_marker FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, DATEADD(minute, 1, minute_marker) FROM by_minute WHERE DATEADD(minute, 1, minute_marker) < datetime_to
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    by_minute
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` allows SQL Server to keep recursively generating the minutes beyond the default of 100.  Still, I would not recommend this if the intervals being generated are more than a few hundred minutes long *(maybe up to one day [1440 minutes])*.

In such a case the simpler approach would be to utilise a table of numbers, and simply join on to that.

An example for creating such a table could be : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/

From there, you just join on the number of row that you need...

```
SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    DATEADD(minute, Numbers.[Number], yourTable.datetime_from)  AS minute_marker
FROM
    yourTable
INNER JOIN
     dbo.Numbers
         ON  Numbers.[Number] >= 0
         AND Numbers.[Number] <  DATEDIFF(minute, yourTable.datetime_from, yourTable.datetime_to)
```

Another recommendation I have is to NOT use 59th second to represent the end of a minute.  What if you get data at 59.600 seconds?  That's after then end of the minute but before the start of the new one?  Instead use markers that are Inclusive Start and Exclusive End...

```
The first minute of 2012 = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' -> '2012-01-01 00:01:00.000'
The final minute of 2012 = '2012-12-31 23:59:00.000' -> '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

With such a structure you only ever need `my_point_in_time >= start AND my_point_in_time < end`, and you never need worry about the precision of the datatypes being used.

*(It also matches human natural language.  When we say things like `between 1 and 2` we most often mean `>= 1 AND < 2`.)*